# How to change tab in Google Chrome with the keyboard, in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, browser, usability

In OSX, you can browse tabs in browsers by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd>/<kbd>p</kbd> or similar. 
I have not found any keys in Ubuntu 14.04.

How can you browse tabs of browsers by keyboard in Ubuntu?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: Not related to Ubuntu, but just in addition to your question, it is also possible to navigation between tabs in OSX with `fn` + `Ctrl`+ `⌃` or `fn` + `Ctrl` + `⌃`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Chrome and Firefox both we have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Number</kbd>

E.g. If you want to go to the tab then you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: Great! Any keyboard binding for back and forth?

Comment: not required just use it

Comment: Assume you have 30 tabs. You will be in trouble in moving your fingers in each tab. I really would like to have previous and next -movements for tabs.

Comment: use ctrl+tab and ctrl+tab+shift

Comment: `Ctrl` + `1` to `8` switches to tab 1 to 8, but `Ctrl` + `9` switches to the last tab

Comment: what about my 12th tab TT

Comment: `Ctrl` + `PagegUp/PageDown` also work

Answer (score 67):

Most shortcuts in other systems also apply:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> = next tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> = previous tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> = new tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> = close tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> = reopen last closed tab

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: `shift+ctrl+tab` also handles previous closed tab. Is there any option for previous current tab?

Comment: ctrl+shift+t handles the previously closed tab.

Comment: so much helpful

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the answers already given: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> should also work to switch tabs forth and back.

Comment: @Masi The same goes for me. I never bothered with Ctrl+Tab etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find full list of shortcuts for Chrome [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en)

Worth to mention from the list (which wasn't mentioned here yet):

Jump to the **last** tab    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>